# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Session never expires

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-state, session-timeout, asp.net-mvc-5

I've an MVC 5 - based web project and i using `HttpSessionStateWrapper` class to work with session state.
Basicaly i store some user-specific data in session state.
Here is my code (without context):

```
public class Util
{
        private HttpSessionStateWrapper _session;

        public Util()
        {
            _session = new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session);
        }

        public T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
        {
            var sessionedObject = (T)_session[key];
            if (sessionedObject != null)
            {
                Logger.Instance.LogDebug("Object returned from session. Session Timeout=" + _session.Timeout.ToString() + " Session Id=" + _session.SessionID);
                return sessionedObject;
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

The instance of `Util` class is created one time and serves as a static property for another singleton type.
And i've some logging here. So, timeout of session state set to 1 minute via Web.config.
But it seems session never epxires for me even within 10 minutes.

Moreover, i noted than on each request `SessionId` is new, but when getting data from session, the id is equal to first-time generated session id.
`Session End` event also never fired for me, but `Session Start` does.
Here is some logs:

```
2013-11-11 04:27:38.2578 App Starting 

2013-11-11 04:27:38.6641 Session onStart. Id=0x545pyzbt4e1vzh1h1rr5d5 
2013-11-11 04:27:38.6641 Object returned from session. Session Timeout=1 Session Id=0x545pyzbt4e1vzh1h1rr5d5 

2013-11-11 04:28:06.5263 Session onStart. Id=ujuxasiz5hvzbv15gbvuuxt3  
2013-11-11 04:28:06.5263 Object returned from session. Session Timeout=1 Session Id=0x545pyzbt4e1vzh1h1rr5d5 

2013-11-11 04:29:00.3432 Session onStart. Id=jgwmmh1ubokxn3kfadevfnph 
2013-11-11 04:29:00.3432 Object returned from session. Session Timeout=1 Session Id=0x545pyzbt4e1vzh1h1rr5d5 

2013-11-11 04:39:25.7919 Session onStart. Id=0mocujzp4tbwwvgnkx1mn0qi 
2013-11-11 04:39:25.7919 Object returned from session. Session Timeout=1 Session Id=0x545pyzbt4e1vzh1h1rr5d5
```

**EDIT**:
Thanks for replies guys! I decide to refuse using session state at all due to have no time to deep debuging this stuff, and use `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection, it will serve my needs

Answer (score 1):

I think you get a new session on each request because you're not storing anything in the session.

Try adding the following to Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Session_Start() 
{ 
    // Since .NET 2.0 ASP.NET will create a new session for each request 
    // unless some data is stored in the session, so here we go... 
    Session["dummy"] = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Already tried it, the result is still same - new session id per each request. That is not main problem, i wonder why "first" session never expires. Since Util class is a part of singleton, it initated only one time per App life cycle, That is why it looks in "first" session state all times, but why that session never expires

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving the application **inactive** for a few minutes (running in `debug mode`) and add a break point to:

```
protected void Session_Start() {}
```

in the `Global.asax` file, and see if this is hit when you return to the application.  This should confirm that the session is actually being terminated.

You could also log the `Session ID`, and log this using `Tracing` to see when the `ID` changes.

Answer (score 1):

If there are some serious problems in your app or you have a lot of memory leaks, your IIS app poll will restart the application and you will have exaclty this behaviour. See your system event log. IIs log.